# Is dark matter present in all galaxies?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

The rotation speeds of nearby galaxies like M31 or our own milky way are determined by observations. And we know there that luminous mass does not explain the rotation curve. Are there any galaxies whose rotation speeds we do not know? Maybe there are galaxies whose rotation curves have not been observed and luminous matter explains the rotation curves?

Comment: See https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/53314/

Comment: As written this is unanswerable.  We cannot guarantee dark matter exists, never mind if it is present in all galaxies.   Galaxies whose rotation curves are not known provide no information to us so we cannot use that lack of knowledge to infer that that their rotation curves (which we don't know) are explained by just luminous matter.

Answer (score 3):

> Is dark matter present in all galaxies ?

Dark matter appears to be present in the majority of galaxies for which we can measure rotation curves. There have been suggestions that a small number of observed galaxies contain little or no dark matter (see [this Scientific American article](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/dark-matter-may-be-missing-from-this-newfound-galaxy-astronomers-say/) for a summary) but these findings are controversial.

> Are there any galaxies whose rotation speeds we do not know ?

Yes. There are many galaxies that are either too distant or too faint or at the wrong orientation to us to allow an accurate measurement of their rotation curves. Note, however, that the evidence for dark matter does not *just* come from galaxy rotation curves. The observed dynamics of galaxy clusters also provide evidence for dark matter, as does the inference of mass distributions from gravitational lensing.

> Maybe there are galaxies whose rotation curves have not been observed and luminous matter explains the rotation curves ?

Maybe - you can assert anything you like about something which has not been observed (see [Russell's teapot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot)).